# Font size for comments in Collective article is bigger than comments on a normal post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, collectives, articles

While engaging with an article within the [Collective section](https://stackoverflow.com/at/68104924/12349734), I noticed a discrepancy in the font size of comments compared to regular posts. Specifically, the font size in the Collective seems larger than in a regular post.

**Font Size in Collective Article:**

[image: Font from Collective]

**Font Size in Regular Post:**

[image: Font from Regular Post]

**Note**: You probably won't see a difference between these two provided images that I posted. So, it's best to view it yourself on a real post. Hence:

- [Link to a comment in Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android?noredirect=1#comment135502647_68104924)
- [Link to a regular comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76820075/library-not-loaded-rpath-webrtc-framework-webrtc-reason-tried-unity-webrt?noredirect=1#comment135486635_76820075)

**Can someone clarify if this is intentional or possibly an oversight?**

---

- Chrome version 115.0.5790.170 (Official Build) (arm64)
- MacOS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The larger font size for *comments* is intentional on **Articles**. Since you can't *answer* an article, we chose to make *comments* more prominent as the primary way another user can engage with the content. The font size is larger and the input field for adding a comment is automatically expanded (instead of having to click the 'Add a comment' link first). The same changes are on **Collections** as well.